# Docker-compose .NET API not running properly

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and have created a simple app where I have a .NET 7 API, Angular UI, and a SQL Server db. I am attempting to containerize the whole project and am running into an issue where when I try to run all containers, the API doesn't seem to be accessible. During development, I would let Visual Studio start the docker-compose I had for the API/Db and everything worked perfect. If I try to start a docker-compose outside of Visual Studio, I can no longer call the API or see the Swagger page when I go to the localhost.

The folder structure for my project is like so:

```
-App
   -UI
      Dockerfile
   -Api
      -ResultsApi
         Dockerfile
   docker-compose 
   docker-compose.override
```

my API Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ResultsApi/ResultsApi.csproj", "ResultsApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ResultsApi/ResultsApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ResultsApi"
RUN dotnet build "ResultsApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ResultsApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ResultsApi.dll"]
```

My docker-compose is:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
    backend:
    frontend:

services:
  database:
    container_name: app-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    ports:
        - 8002:1433
    environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=password@123 
    volumes:
        - db_data:/var/lib/mysql 
    networks:
        - backend
  resultsapi:
    container_name: app-api
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}resultsapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: API\ResultsApi\Dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - database
    environment:
        - DB_HOST=database
        - DB_NAME=Results     
        - DB_SA_PASSWORD=password@123
    networks:
        - backend
        - frontend
  ui:
    image: my-movies
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: UI\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4200:80'
    networks:
      - frontend


volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

and my docker-compose.override

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  resultsapi:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

when starting up my containers I use the command

```
docker-compose -f docker.compose.yml -f docker.compose.override.yml up
```

when visiting localhost:4200 I can see and interact with my UI, but when going to localhost:8001 or localhost:8001/swagger/index.html the message that displays is:

This site can’t provide a secure connection localhost sent an invalid response.

Or when trying to call the API via the UI:

net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: _"but the API portion is having the problem"_ please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: @phuzi I updated the post and put some details at the bottom

Comment: Not sure if it's related but the port mapping looks a bit suspicious to me. Port 80 is normally for HTTP traffic but it sounds like the requests to the external port 8001 are being done via HTTPS.

Comment: @phuzi I tried setting the port to 8001:443 and when loading localhost:8001 the message is now "This page isn’t working localhost didn’t send any data."